# Vogal no nome completo C#

Tags: c#

Preciso de uma ajuda, estou fazendo um exercício, para verificar a existência da quantas vogais 'a' tem num nome, mas meu debug, aponta o vetor sempre com o caracter '\0', estou tentando inserir o Length dentro do for, para corrigir, alguém sabe, a melhor maneira de se obter?

```
namespace Console_Vogal_Matriz
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] nome_completo = new char[5];
            int vogal = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Digite o seu nome completo ", nome_completo);
            Console.ReadLine();
            for (int conta = 0; nome_completo[conta]!='\0'; conta++)
            {
                if (nome_completo[conta] == 'a'){
                    vogal++;
                    Console.WriteLine("Total de ", vogal + "letras");
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embora a resposta do Thiago Loureiro resolva boa parte do problema, por se tratar de um exercício, achei válido deixar uma resposta explicando alguns pontos importantes que vão esclarecer suas dúvidas, porque me parece que o exercício é, de fato, direcionado ao trabalho com vetores e um fluxo de entrada e saída do seu programa.

Existem vários erros na sua lógica e implementação. O vetor sempre apresenta 5 posições com valor `\0` porque no início de seu código você o declara dessa forma,
 `char[] nome_completo = new char[5];`
 e nunca o popula, o resultado é um array de char com 5 posições vazias.

O método `WriteLine()` serve para você escrever coisas no console, e não para ler informações o comando abaixo não atribuir o valor de entrada para a sua varíavel:

```
Console.WriteLine("Digite o seu nome completo: ", nome_completo);
```

Sua aplicação seria no caso de você já ter um valor inicial declarado para `nome_completo`, mas ainda assim não faria muito sentido, segue um exemplo de uma aplicação mais usual com esse overload e um placeholder;

```
char caractere = 'a'; //poderia ser uma string
Console.WriteLine("Digite o seu nome completo: (iremos contar a quantidade do caractere \"{0}\")", caractere);
```

Veja que o seu `Console.ReadLine();` não atribui valor nenhum para ele e mesmo que o fizesse a entrada não poderia ter mais de 5 caracteres, pois ultrapassaria o limite pré estabelecido para o seu vetor e ainda assim encontraria um erro porque o método `ReadLine()` retorna de fato um tipo `string` e não um `char[]`, sendo necessária a seguinte conversão:

```
nome_completo = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
```

Porém ainda assim você encontraria um erro, por mais que você atribua um valor inicial maior para o seu vetor, digamos `new char[1024]` e atribua seu valor através do `ReadLine().TocharArray()`, a sua declaração no for resultará em um novo erro, pois agora que foi atribuído um valor ao seu vetor ele não possui mais posições vazias e sua condição `nome_completo[conta] != '\0'` nunca será false, resultando em erro de índice por que `conta` continuará sendo incrementada além do tamanho de `nome_completo`

Depois vem a sua comparação para encontrar a vogal "a", você está testando o caractere 'a' que é diferente de 'A' ou 'á' ou 'ã' e etc. Além disso, dentro do mesmo bloco você está escrevendo o resultado como total (que na verdade é parcial) e fazendo o programa esperar por conta do `ReadLine()`.

Não obstante, o seu `WriteLine()` possui um erro de sintaxe que não informa de fato o valor atribuído ao contador `vogal`. Nesse caso seria utilizada a mesma técnica apresentada no início da resposta.

```
//O problema está na "," em  '"Total de ",'
//Console.WriteLine("Total de ", vogal + "letras");
Console.WriteLine("Total de {0} letras", vogal);
```

Segue abaixo uma revisão do código, aplicando os pontos observados anteriormente, mas recomendo que você vá fazendo as alterações conforme apresentadas na resposta para que possa ir entendendo melhor as causas e consequências:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int vogal = 0;
    char[] caracteres =  { 'a', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'à' };

    Console.WriteLine("Digite o seu nome completo:");

    char[] nome_completo = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().ToCharArray();

    for (int conta = 0; conta < nome_completo.Length; conta++)
    {
        if (caracteres.Contains(nome_completo[conta]))
        {
            vogal++;               
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Total de {0} letras \"{1}\".", vogal, caracteres[0]);
    Console.Read();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: estava vindo adicionar uma lista de vogais também ;) +1

Comment: boa mestre, valeu por adicionar mais conteúdo! Sempre é bom incrementar! :)

Comment: Obrigado pelas observações Leandro Angelo, aprendi bastante dos conceitos.

Answer (score 2):

Tem uma forma mais simples, joga o retorno do ReadLine em uma string e depois conta com Linq

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string nome_completo = String.Empty;
            int vogal = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Digite o seu nome completo ");
            nome_completo = Console.ReadLine();

            int count = nome_completo.Count(f => f == 'a');

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```